# Set OptionSetValue to null in Dynamics CRM Plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I´ve already found a similar question but the answer just did'nt work for me so I wondered if there might be lilke any newer information on this topic.

What I want to do is assign null to an OptionSetValue.
What I've tried so far:

- someEntity.Attributes["myfield"] = 899270000; //Works
- someEntity.Attributes["myfield"] = null; //Not working
- someEntity.Attributes["myfield"] = 0; //Not working
- someEntity.Attributes["myfield"] = -1; //Also not working

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing

```
someEntity["myfield"] = null;
service.Update(someEntity);
```

Or the strong stype equivalent:

```
someEntity.myfield = null;
service.Update(someEntity);
```

Should definetely work.

Comment: As you can see above, thats what I´ve already tried. Still getting a "Out of range" exception here.

Comment: Is that really an option set field? Cause I've been setting them to null for ages like that.

Comment: I would say yes, cause when I set someEntity["myfield"] = new OptionSetValue(indexOfOption) it works. Its an very easy OptionSet with only two values ("yes" and "no") but in this case I want to set it to the default value which is "--" (unassigned).

Comment: Urgh. Forgett all that. It was an Exception which occured much earlier but on the same field. So sorry.